# Preventing queuing during multiple .animation events

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this).animate({'backgroundColor':'red'},600)
       .animate({'color':'#fff'},600);
```

How can I make both `.animate` events happen at the same time instead of the second one waiting for the first one to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying them in the same `animate` call:

```
$(this).animate({
   'backgroundColor':'red',
   'color':'#fff'
},600);
```

Comment: What if it's `.animate` and something like `.toggleClass` though?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify multiple things that change in your animate statement.

```
$(this).animate({
    'backgroundColor':'red',
    'color':'#fff'
} ,600);
```

It's right there in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for `.animate()`.